# Divisibility for digits of consecutive numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

For a given positive integer $n$, we write down the digits of $n$, followed by those of $n+1$, $n+2$, and so on. For which $d$ is it always true that regardless of $n$, there exists $k$ such that after writing down the digits of $n+k$, all the current digits form a number divisible by $d$?

This is true for numbers $d$ such that if a number $r$ is divisible by $d$, then any number ending with $r$ is also divisible by $d$. For example, any $r$ ending with $00$ is divisible by $100$, so $d=100$ works. More generally, $d=2^a5^b$ fits this category. $d=3$ and $d=9$ also works by a sum-of-digit analysis.

Comment: Can you give any example of $n$ and $d$ where there is no such $k$?

Comment: $d=9$ is working as well. My guess is that there is always such a $k$ , but this is only an intuitive guess. Currently, I have no idea how to prove it.

Comment: $d = 11$ starting at $n = 2$ works but it takes a long time: you need to go all the way up to writing down $104$, if I didn't make a mistake...

Comment: @QiaochuYuan Correct, we actually have to go until $104$.

Comment: If $d=7$ and the start value is $99\ 980$ , we need to go until $10^6+14$

Answer (score 2):

**Added** : I've added the following claim (4) :

(4) $d=D\cdot 2^s\cdot 5^t$ works where $s,t$ are non-negative integers, and $D$ is such that there is a positive integer $m$ satisfying $10^m\equiv -1\pmod D$.

---

This is a partial answer.

This answer proves the following claims :

(1) $d$ which is such that there exists a positive integer $m$ satisfying $10^m\equiv -1\pmod d$ works.

(2) $d=3\cdot 2^s\cdot 5^t$ where $s,t$ are non-negative integers works.

(3) $d=3^2\cdot 2^s\cdot 5^t$ where $s,t$ are non-negative integers works.

---

(1) $d$ which is such that there exists a positive integer $m$ satisfying $10^m\equiv -1\pmod d$ works.

*Proof* :

In the following, let me write $\overline n\ \overline{n+1}\ \cdots \ \overline{n+k}$ as $[n,n+k]$. $\ \ $(For example, $[9,12]$ represents $9101112$.)

There are infinitely many positive integers $m$ such that $$10^m\equiv -1\pmod d\tag1$$

So, for any given $(d,n)$, there exists a positive integer $m$ satisfying $(1)$ and
$$n\lt 10^{m-1}-1\lt 10^{m-1}+2(d-2)-1\lt 10^m\tag2$$

For non-negative integers $k$ satisfying $10^{m-1}+k\lt 10^m$, we have $$[n,10^{m-1}+k]=[n,10^{m-1}+k-1]\times 10^m+10^{m-1}+k$$
Dividing the both sides by $(10^m)^{k}$ and letting $a_k=\frac{[n,10^{m-1}+k]}{(10^m)^{k}}$ give
$$a_{k}-a_{k-1}=\frac{10^{m-1}+k}{(10^m)^{k}}$$
$$a_{k-1}-a_{k-2}=\frac{10^{m-1}+k-1}{(10^m)^{k-1}}$$
$$\vdots$$
$$a_{0}-a_{-1}=\frac{10^{m-1}+0}{(10^m)^{0}}$$
Adding these gives
$$\begin{align}a_k&=a_{-1}+\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{10^{m-1}+j}{(10^m)^{j}}
\\\\&=\frac{[n,10^{m-1}-1]}{(10^m)^{-1}}+10^{m-1}\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{1}{(10^m)^{j}}+\sum_{j=0}^{k}\frac{j}{(10^m)^{j}}
\\\\&=10^m[n,10^{m-1}-1]+\frac{10^{m-1}((10^m)^{k+1}-1)}{(10^m)^k(10^m-1)}+\frac{(10^m)^{k+1}+k-10^m(k+1)}{(10^m)^k(10^m-1)^2}\end{align}$$

Mutiplying the both sides by $(10^m)^k(10^m-1)^2$ gives
$$(10^m-1)^2[n,10^{m-1}+k]=(10^m)^{k+1}(10^m-1)^2[n,10^{m-1}-1]+10^{m-1}((10^m)^{k+1}-1)(10^m-1)+(10^m)^{k+1}+k-10^m(k+1)$$
It follows from $10^m\equiv -1\pmod d$ that
$$4[n,10^{m-1}+k]\equiv 4(-1)^{k+1}[n,10^{m-1}-1]+10^{m-1}((-1)^{k+1}-1)(-2)+(-1)^{k+1}+2k+1\pmod d$$

If $k=2s+1$ is odd, then we have
$$[n,10^{m-1}+2s+1]\equiv [n,10^{m-1}-1]+s+1\pmod d$$

So, taking $m$ satisfying $(1)$ and $(2)$, we obtain
$$[n,10^{m-1}+1]\equiv [n,10^{m-1}-1]+1\pmod d$$
$$[n,10^{m-1}+3]\equiv [n,10^{m-1}-1]+2\pmod d$$
$$\vdots$$
$$[n,10^{m-1}+2(d-2)+1]\equiv [n,10^{m-1}-1]+d-1\pmod d$$

These imply that there exists an integer $s$ satisfying $-1\le s\le d-2$ and $[n,10^{m-1}+2s+1]\equiv 0\pmod d$. $\quad\blacksquare$

---

(2) $d=3\cdot 2^s\cdot 5^t$ where $s,t$ are non-negative integers works.

*Proof* :

$d=3$ works. If $a:=\max(s,t)\ge 1$, then $[n,u\cdot 10^a]$ is divisible by $2^s\cdot 5^t$. Also, we have
$$\small [n,u\cdot 10^a]\equiv \sum_{k=1}^{u\cdot 10^a}k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\equiv \frac{u\cdot 10^a(u\cdot 10^a+1)}{2}-\frac{(n-1)n}{2}\equiv 2u(u+1)-\frac{(n-1)n}{2}\pmod 3$$

So, if $n\not\equiv 2\pmod 3$, then $u=3n$ works. If $n\equiv 2\pmod 3$, then $u=3n+1$ works.$\quad\blacksquare$

---

(3) $d=3^2\cdot 2^s\cdot 5^t$ where $s,t$ are non-negative integers works.

*Proof* :

$d=9$ works. If $a:=\max(s,t)\ge 1$, then $[n,u\cdot 10^a]$ is divisible by $2^s\cdot 5^t$. Also, we have
$$\small [n,u\cdot 10^a]\equiv \sum_{k=1}^{u\cdot 10^a}k-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\equiv \frac{u\cdot 10^a(u\cdot 10^a+1)}{2}-\frac{(n-1)n}{2}\equiv 5u(u+1)-\frac{(n-1)n}{2}\pmod 9$$

- If $n\equiv 0,1\pmod 9$, then $u=9n$ works.
- If $n\equiv 2,5,8\pmod 9$, then $u=9n+1$ works.
- If $n\equiv 3,7\pmod 9$, then $u=9n+2$ works.
- If $n\equiv 4,6\pmod 9$, then $u=9k+3$ works. $\quad\blacksquare$

---

**Added** :

(4) $d=D\cdot 2^s\cdot 5^t$ works where $s,t$ are non-negative integers, and $D$ is such that there is a positive integer $m$ satisfying $10^m\equiv -1\pmod D$.

*Proof* :

From the proof for the claim (1), we see that if $n\lt 10^{m-1}+k\lt 10^m$ and $10^{m}\equiv -1\pmod D$, then
$$4[n,10^{m-1}+k]\equiv 4(-1)^{k+1}[n,10^{m-1}-1]+10^{m-1}((-1)^{k+1}-1)(-2)+(-1)^{k+1}+2k+1\pmod D$$

Considering $k=(20u-2)10^{a-1}$ where triplets of positive integers $(u,a,m)$ satisfies $$n\lt 10^{m-1}+(20u-2)10^{a-1}\lt 10^m,$$
$$1+\max(s,t)\le a\lt m,\qquad 10^a\equiv 10^m\equiv -1\pmod D,$$
$$n\lt 10^{m-1}+(20\cdot 1-2)10^{a-1}\lt 10^{m-1}+(20D-2)10^{a-1}\lt 10^m$$
(for any given $(D,s,t,n)$, such $(u,a,m)$ always exist since there are infinitely many $m$ satisfying $10^m\equiv -1\pmod D$) we have
$$4[n,10^{m-1}+(20u-2)10^{a-1}]\equiv -4[n,10^{m-1}-1]+4\cdot 10^{m-1}+2(20u-2)10^{a-1}\pmod D$$
Multiplying the both sides by $5$ and using $10^a\equiv 10^m\equiv -1\pmod D$ give
$$20[n,10^{m-1}+(20u-2)10^{a-1}]\equiv -20[n,10^{m-1}-1]-20u\pmod D$$
Since $\gcd(D,20)=1$, we can divide the both sides by $20$ to have
$$[n,10^{m-1}+(20u-2)10^{a-1}]\equiv -[n,10^{m-1}-1]-u\pmod D$$

So, we obtain
$$[n,10^{m-1}+(20\cdot 1-2)10^{a-1}]\equiv -[n,10^{m-1}-1]-1\pmod D$$
$$[n,10^{m-1}+(20\cdot 2-2)10^{a-1}]\equiv -[n,10^{m-1}-1]-2\pmod D$$
$$\vdots$$
$$[n,10^{m-1}+(20D-2)10^{a-1}]\equiv -[n,10^{m-1}-1]-D\pmod D$$

These imply that there is an integer $u$ satisfying $1\le u\le D$ and $[n,10^{m-1}+(20u-2)10^{a-1}]\equiv 0\pmod d$.$\quad\blacksquare$

Answer (score 0):

The number formed by writing digits of $n, n+1, n+2, \dots, n+k$ will be of the form

$$y = c \times 10^{\lfloor \log_{10} (n+k) \rfloor} + (n+k)$$

We denote this as $\langle n, k\rangle$. If we multiply this by $10^a$, we denote this as $\langle n, k\rangle \times 10^a$.

**Case 1:**

If $d | (n+k)$ and $d | 10^{\lceil \log_{10} (n+k) \rceil}$ then $d | y$.

If $g = GCD(n+k, 10^{\lceil \log_{10} (n+k) \rceil}) \ne 1$, then $d \in$ the set of divisors of $g$.

**Case 2:**

There are other $d$ that are divisors of the GCD of partitions of $y$ coming from the partial sums

$$y = \langle n, r \rangle \times 10^{\delta} + \langle r+1, n+k\rangle, n \lt r \lt n+k$$

i.e.,

$$g = GCD(\langle n, r \rangle \times 10^{\delta}, \langle r+1, n+k\rangle)$$

If $g \ne 1, d \in $ the set of divisors of $g$.